# How to get the value of an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I have to take each data of the array inside an array but it doesn't work when I use something like `tmp.name` or `tmp[0].name` would result `undefined` and even `tmp.length` result `0`

```
var tmp = [];
var db = firebase.firestore();
var docCollection = db.collection('doctors');
var assignedDoctors = docCollection.where('assign', '==', user.key).get();

assignedDoctors.then(function(doc){
  let i = 0;
  doc.forEach(function(md){
    tmp.push(md.data());
    tmp[i].key = md.id;
    i++;
  });
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
console.log(tmp)
```

the tmp result

> []
>       0: {assign: "userA", name: "NameA"}
>       1: {assign: "userA", name: "NameB"}
>       length: 2
>       __proto_: Array(0)

Comment: `assignedDoctors` is a promise. Promises are `async`, you output `tmp` before the promise is fulfilled. Move `console.log(tmp)` inside the promise.

Comment: @darklightcode but I need it outside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = [];
var db = firebase.firestore();
var docCollection = db.collection('doctors');
var assignedDoctors = docCollection.where('assign', '==', user.key).get();

assignedDoctors.then(function(doc){
  let i = 0;
  doc.forEach(function(md){
    tmp.push(md.data());
   // tmp[i].key = md.id;
   // i++;
  });
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
console.log(tmp)
```

comment these line and check it.

Comment: let test = [];
    let array = [];
    test.push('hi', 'hello', 'kkk');
    console.log(test[0]);
   for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
     array.push(test[i]);
   }
    console.log(array); I did in type script but not your code same as like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare map and assign all data of `md.data()` to map and then push map into array and remove variable `i` as no need of it. Like following:

```
doc.forEach(function(md){
    var map = {};
    map = md.data();
    map.key = md.id;
    tmp.push(map);
  });
```

Comment: map.key has an error it says "key does not exist on type {}"